# SignalR ConnectionData empty, and won't connect

Tags: c#, signalr

I have two SignalR hubs in my MVC app, `ChatHub` and `AnotherHub`. `ChatHub` is working nicely, but I can't connect to the other one. I know that SignalR recognises that `AnotherHub` exists, because I'm getting the following JavaScript in /signalr/hubs:

```
signalR.chatHub = {
    _: {
        hubName: 'ChatHub',
        ignoreMembers: ['post'],
        connection: function () { return signalR.hub; }
    },

    post: function (room, message) {
        return invoke(this, "Post", $.makeArray(arguments));
    }
};

signalR.anotherHub = {
    _: {
        hubName: 'AnotherHub',
        ignoreMembers: ['doSomething'],
        connection: function () { return signalR.hub; }
    },

    doSomething: function (thing) {
        return invoke(this, "DoSomething", $.makeArray(arguments));
    }
};
```

On the chat page, Fiddler tells me the following when connecting with `/signalr/signalr/connect`:

```
connectionData      [{"name":"chathub"}]
tid                 10
```

However, when trying to connect to `anotherHub`, Fiddler says:

```
connectionData      []
tid                 3
```

My javascript on the chat page:

```
        cn = $.connection.chatHub;
        $.connection.hub.start();
```

and on the another page:

```
        cn = $.connection.anotherHub;
        $.connection.hub.start();
```

Now, a curious thing; when I change `anotherHub` to `chatHub` on the another page, the connection works. When I change `chatHub` to `anotherHub` on the chat page, that also works. The only combination that doesn't is `anotherHub` on the another page.  (I've confirmed this by server-side breakpoints on the hubs' constructors and checking fiddler for the ConnectionData parameter). Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't register for any callbacks on anotherHub, connectionData will be empty.

Comment: Given that it works if I use the chatHub on the another page, and vice versa, what should I do?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same error. I have 2 hubs but the connectionData on the second hub is empty. I have setup callbacks and its just not working.

Comment: Sorry, no. I decided to use one hub and route things through different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have referenced all of the same JS libraries (especially /signalr/hubs) on the another page?

Comment: Yes, quite sure. I can connect to the `chatHub` on the another page, just not the `anotherHub`.