# signalr empty connection data on my second hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

i have had one signalr hub for the past year working with no problems.
today when attempting to add a second hub, its just not working.
i have followed the same steps as the first one to no avail.

here is the output of my ~/signalr/hubs

```
 // Create hub signalR instance
$.extend(signalR, {
    errorPageHub: {
        _: {
            hubName: 'Web.Infrastructure.Logging.Broadcasting.ErrorPageHub',
            ignoreMembers: ['error', 'event', 'warning', 'success', 'namespace', 'ignoreMembers', 'callbacks'],
            connection: function () { return signalR.hub; }
        },

        error: function (error, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "Error", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        event: function (eventDescription, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "Event", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        warning: function (warning, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "Warning", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        success: function (success, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "Success", $.makeArray(arguments));
        }
    },
    pulsePageHub: {
        _: {
            hubName: 'Web.Infrastructure.Logging.Broadcasting.PulsePageHub',
            ignoreMembers: ['tenderAdded', 'tenderUpdated', 'projectAdded', 'projectUpdated', 'namespace', 'ignoreMembers', 'callbacks'],
            connection: function () { return signalR.hub; }
        },

        tenderAdded: function (message, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "TenderAdded", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        tenderUpdated: function (message, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "TenderUpdated", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        projectAdded: function (message, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "ProjectAdded", $.makeArray(arguments));
        },

        projectUpdated: function (message, callback) {
            return serverCall(this, "ProjectUpdated", $.makeArray(arguments));
        }
    }
});
```

on my page using the "errorPageHub" when i call

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }, function () {
        console.log('connection started!');
    });
```

the following is output to firebug ::

```
connectionData  [{"name":"Web.Infrastructure.Logging.Broadcasting.ErrorPageHub","methods":["addError","addSuccess","addWarning","addEvent"]}]
connectionId    1806c3f7-e2e0-4ec7-9eb1-670a43fac912
transport   longPolling
```

the connectiondata corresponds with the hub i am initialising on my page.
now on the page where i am trying to use the pulsePageHub the following is output to firebug when using the same connection.hub.start call (please note these are on different pages, i only have one call to connection.start on a page)

```
connectionData  []
connectionId    05b2354d-63ac-469a-bf0b-bd4e06e56426
transport   longPolling
```

i am initialising the pulseHub in the exact same way i am doing my errorPageHub, but the connectiondata is always empty and therefore it never picks up any broadcasts. if i add the errorPageHub initialisation to this page, the only connectionData sent is the errorPageHub.

how do i initialise this second hub to receive broadcasts? this question is very similar to the one posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859861/signalr-connectiondata-empty-and-wont-connect) but it was never resolved

My hubs are declared on the client side like so ::

```
        var error = $.connection.errorPageHub;

    error.addError = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "error");

    };

    error.addSuccess = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "info");
    };

    error.addWarning = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "warning");
    };


    error.addEvent = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "info");
    };
}
```

and my pulse page hub like so :

```
  var pulse = $.connection.pulsePageHub;

    pulse.tenderAdded = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "info");
        alert("hi");
    };

    pulse.tenderUpdated = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "warning");
        alert("hi");
    };

    pulse.projectAdded = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "info");
        alert("hi");
    };

    pulse.projectUpdated = function (message) {
        appendMessage(message, "warning");
        alert("hi");
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of SignalR are you using?

You need to wire up event handlers for the hub's you're interested in before starting the connection. That is:

hub.client.something = function() { };

Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: its an older version, there is no .client property.
my error page hub is initialised like so

 var error = $.connection.errorPageHub;


  error.addError = function (message) {
            appendMessage(message, "error");

        };


        error.addSuccess = function (message) {
            appendMessage(message, "info");
        };


        error.addWarning = function (message) {
            appendMessage(message, "warning");
        };



        error.addEvent = function (message) {
            appendMessage(message, "info");
        };

Comment: can't get code to look nice in a comment :( will update my post

Comment: is it just a js update or do i need to build the source and re-add dll's etc? we're not using nuget.

Comment: There have been significant changes to SignalR since the `.client` property was added to JS hubs. Both the SignalR dll's and the JS library will need to be updated.

Comment: updated this morning, its all good now.
marking this as the correct answer as the first line questions my version.